# jQuery - Changing CSS from Array on keyup

Tags: jquery

Each time I click a radio, the `.tag` div receives the `data-color` of the corresponding radio.

How do I apply the same principle to `input type="text"` where each radio value `data-color` is put into an `array` and the `background-color` of the `.tag` changes based on the value of the input entered on `keyup`?

I need the array to be in a `range` for example if the value is between $25-$49 return the data-color of the radio where value="25" since the next radio value="50" and if typed, would return the data-color for the valu="50" radio.

**For example**:

```
    ("0-5"   -> data-color of first radio) 

    ("6-25"  -> data-color of second radio)  
    
    ("26-50" -> data-color of third radio) 

    ("26-50" -> data-color of fourth radio) 
    
    ("100+" -> custom background-color)
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#donation").keyup(function() {
    $("input:radio[name=donation]").each(function() {
      $(this).prop("checked", false);
    });
  });
  $('input[name="donation"]').on("change", function() {
    var color = $(this).attr("data-color");
    $(".tag").css("background-color", color);
    $("#donation").closest("div").removeClass("donation--active");
    $("#donation").val(
      this.checked ?
      this.value :
      $('input[name="donation"][name="' + this.name + '"]:checked').val()
    );
  });
  $('input[name="donation"]').trigger("change");
});
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #b6b6b6;
}

:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #b6b6b6;
  opacity: 1;
}

::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #b6b6b6;
  opacity: 1;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #b6b6b6;
}

::-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #b6b6b6;
}

::placeholder {
  color: #b6b6b6;
}

body {
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 30px;
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 540px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.inline-radio {
  font-size: 19px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.inline-radio div {
  border: 1px solid #ededed;
  margin-top: -1px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
}

.inline-radio div:last-child {
  color: #b6b6b6;
  padding: 0 0.9rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.inline-radio input[type="radio"] {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.inline-radio input[type="text"] {
  color: #b6b6b6;
  font-size: inherit;
  margin-left: 0.3rem;
  display: flex;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: #0000ff00
}

.inline-radio label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #b6b6b6;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.inline-radio input:checked+label {
  border: 2px solid
}

.tag {
  height: 120px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid
}

input#donation {
  border: 3px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inline-radio">
  <div><input type="radio" data-color="blue" value="5" name="donation"><label>$5</label></div>
  <div><input type="radio" data-color="orange" value="25" name="donation" checked><label>$25</label></div>
  <div><input type="radio" data-color="green" value="50" name="donation"><label>$50</label></div>
  <div><input type="radio" data-color="red" value="100" name="donation"><label>$100</label></div>
  <div><span>$</span><input id="donation" value="" name="donation" type="text"></div>
</div>
<div class="tag"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this line on `keyup` and outside `.each()` >>

`$('input[name="donation"][value="'+$(this).val()+'"]').prop("checked" , true).change();`

- `$(this).val()` is the value of the text input
- `'input[name="donation"][value="'+$(this).val()+'"]'` select the radio input which his value has the same text input's value
- `.prop("checked" , true)` .. make it checked
- `.change()` trigger the change event

**Updated:**

> **OP Comment** I need this to be in a range. So any value between $25-$49 returns the data-color of the radio where value="25" since the
> next radio value=''50". I have updated the question to try and clarify
> the requirement

- Add `data-min` and `data-max` attribute to your radio inputs
- Use `filter()` to filter the input which text input's value match between data-min/max
- Use a boolen variable to stop the change event to change the value in the text input on keyup

---

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var FormInputEvent = false;
  var color = false; // <<<< here
  var Over100Color = "black"; //<<<< here
  var changeColor = function(el = null){
    color = (color == false || FormInputEvent == false) ? $(el).attr("data-color") : color;
    //console.log(color);
    $(".tag").css("background-color", color);
    $("#donation").closest("div").removeClass("donation--active");
  };
  $("#donation").on('input',function(e) {
    var Value = $(this).val();
    $("input:radio[name=donation]").prop("checked", false);
    FormInputEvent = true;
    color = Value > 100 ? Over100Color : false; // <<<< here
    if(Value > 100){
      changeColor();
    }else{
      $('input[name="donation"]').each(function(){
        if (Value >= +$(this).data('min') && Value <= +$(this).data('max')){
          $(this).prop('checked' , true);
          changeColor(this);
        }
      });
    }
  });
  
  $('input[name="donation"]').on("change", function() {
    changeColor(this);
    if(FormInputEvent == false){
      $("#donation").val(
        this.checked ?
        this.value :
        $('input[name="donation"][name="' + this.name + '"]:checked').val()
      );
    }
    FormInputEvent = false;
  }).filter(':checked').change();
  
});
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #b6b6b6;
}

:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #b6b6b6;
  opacity: 1;
}

::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #b6b6b6;
  opacity: 1;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #b6b6b6;
}

::-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #b6b6b6;
}

::placeholder {
  color: #b6b6b6;
}

body {
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 30px;
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 540px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.inline-radio {
  font-size: 19px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.inline-radio div {
  border: 1px solid #ededed;
  margin-top: -1px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
}

.inline-radio div:last-child {
  color: #b6b6b6;
  padding: 0 0.9rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.inline-radio input[type="radio"] {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.inline-radio input[type="text"] {
  color: #b6b6b6;
  font-size: inherit;
  margin-left: 0.3rem;
  display: flex;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: #0000ff00
}

.inline-radio label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #b6b6b6;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.inline-radio input:checked+label {
  border: 2px solid
}

.tag {
  height: 120px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid
}

input#donation {
  border: 3px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inline-radio">
  <div><input type="radio" data-color="blue" value="5" name="donation" data-min="0" data-max="5"><label>$5</label></div>
  <div><input type="radio" data-color="orange" value="25" name="donation" data-min="6" data-max="25" checked><label>$25</label></div>
  <div><input type="radio" data-color="green" value="50" name="donation" data-min="26" data-max="50"><label>$50</label></div>
  <div><input type="radio" data-color="red" value="100" name="donation" data-min="51" data-max="100"><label>$100</label></div>
  <div><span>$</span><input id="donation" value="" name="donation" type="text"></div>
</div>
<div class="tag"></div>
```

Comment: I need this to be in a range. So any value between $25-$49 returns the data-color of the radio where value="25" since the next radio value=''50". I have updated the question to try and clarify the requirement

Comment: Working except how do I add a new color for when the value exceeds 100?

Comment: @KyleJohn answer updated .. read `// <<<< here` code lines .. change `blue` with any color you want

Comment: Thanks for the update. The radio buttons are not working on change and over100 should work on keyup as you currently have to click out of the input to change the color

Comment: I just noticed that the input auto changes the value entered to the `max` of the closest range. The user should still be allowed to enter any value (say 23) and the input should never auto change, I only needed the `background-color` and `checked` label to change, which they do now

Comment: Are you able to update the answer or should I post a new question?